# Change dynamically Item Value on <form:options> in Spring form select

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm using the next Spring form tag on my project:

```
<form:select path="eps.eps_id_eps" id="entidad" style="width: 400px;">
    <form:options items="${EPSs}" />
</form:select>
```

I need to change the "items" values so i can display another data to a same select form tag, i.e. dynamically 'items="${EPSs}"' changes to 'items="${foo}"'

IS THERE Any mode to change items value in js/jquery or by ModelAttribute tag in server side?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Define a controller to receive foo list

```
@RestController
public class FooController{
   @GetMapping("/foo")
   public List<String> getFooItems(@RequestParam String eps){
      return Arrays.asList("foo1","foo2");
   }
}
```

Step 2 : Define a jquery to listen on eps select changes

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#entidad").change(function(){
    var eps = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/foo?eps='+eps,
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(response){
            var len = response.length;
            //clear previous selection, eps_select is the select you want to complete
            $("#eps_select").empty();
            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                var foo = response[i];                    
                $("#eps_select").append("<option value='"+foo+"'>"+foo+"</option>");
            }
          }
        });
     });
 });
```